# Emacs other-window-or-previous-buffer

Tags: emacs, window, buffer

in an effort to reduce the number of keystrokes I have to memorize I'd like to have a function which either

a) switches to the previous buffer when there is only one window/frame
b) switches to the other window/frame (same as other-window-or-frame/other-window/other-frame) if there is another window/frame

So far I have found... nothing! And my elisp skills are... well they are improving but I did not manage to code myself a solution.
Any ideas (or hard-to-find packages) out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an elisp function that switches windows if there are more than one visible, otherwise switches directly to the previous buffer:

```lisp
(defun other-window-or-previous-buffer ()
  "Switches windows if more than one window, otherwise switches buffers."
  (interactive)
  (if (> (count-windows) 1)
      (other-window 1)
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))))
```